# Ajax Multiple Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, parsley.js

I Have a question. I have 2 form on one page boostrap form wizard and i want to post them with ajax one submit button. How can i do this?

```
<form class="form-horizontal form1" role="form" parsley-validate id="form1"></form>
```

And my second Form;

```
<form class="form-horizontal form2" role="form" parsley-validate id="form2"></form>
```

Here's the Javascript I tried:

```
$(function() { 
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) { 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'post', 
            url: '_Interviews.asp?M=AddOK', 
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            success: function () { 
                location.reload(); 
            } 
        }); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Serialise both forms to an array using [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/), merge the arrays and set the resulting array in the `data` parameter of the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Do you want them both to go to the same target url or seperate ones?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thak you. Can you show it by a simple code ?

Comment: @user3154108 same target url.

Comment: @Alp can you show what you've tried already so that I can amend it as needed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan http://shorttext.com/705b2d0 here is the my code.

Comment: I meant your JS code. Also, please use the `edit` button to update your answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan      $(function () {
     $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: '_Interviews.asp?M=AddOK',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function () {
        location.reload();
       }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
     });
    });

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serializeArray()` to create an array of the values from both forms, then `concat()` them together before sending the AJAX request, something like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) { 
    var form1Data = $('.form1').serializeArray();
    var form2Data = $('.form2').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'post', 
        url: '_Interviews.asp?M=AddOK', 
        data: form1Data.concat(form2Data),
        success: function () { 
            location.reload(); 
        } 
    }); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```